# PubSub script not accepting variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a PubSub script on the internet, which works quite well, unfortunately I don't completely understand how it works...

This wasn't a problem until now. For a project I need to call a function via this pubsub script and pass it some arguments. However, the function seems to not accept any arguemnts and only passes the changed variable of its event.

Here is the line of code which subscribes to a PubSub event and calls a function:

```
events.on( 'scrollChanged', self.translate );
```

As you can probably tell, the event is a scroll event and the passed value is the amount of pixels scrolled.

This line stands inside a jQuery plugin, which I'm currently developing and should act as a function call, which we would normally wirte like this: `self.translate()`

Until now, everything works well, but the `translate` function also needs some other variabels from the `init`-function (from which it is called).
So normally I would write:

```
[...]
init: function( options, this ) {
  // Logic
  self.translate(var1, var2); 
},

translate: function( var1, var2 ) {
  // Logic
}
[...]
```

To have the function update while scrolling I need to call it with the `events.on( 'scrollChanged', self.translate );` funtion and also pass the `yScroll` variable for some calculations. But if I pass the two variables to this, I only get error messages which tell me, that the function is undefined.

```
// Exchanged `self.translate(var1, var2);` in the above code by:
events.on( 'scrollChanged', self.translate(var1, var2) );
```

So I'm guessing, that the PubSub code does not accept any other variables?!

Hope that anyone can help me out.

---

**PubSub Code**

```
var events = {
  events: {},
  on: function (eventName, fn) {
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
    this.events[eventName].push(fn);
  },
  off: function(eventName, fn) {
    if (this.events[eventName]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.events[eventName].length; i++) {
        if (this.events[eventName][i] === fn) {
          this.events[eventName].splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      };
    }
  },
  emit: function (eventName, data) {
    if (this.events[eventName]) {
      this.events[eventName].forEach(function(fn) {
        fn(data);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The error occurs in this line of the `emit`-function:

> fn(data);

and tells me, that `fn` is not defined.

Here's the code of the `emit` which works well, if no arguments are passed:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var yScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  events.emit('scrollChanged', yScroll);
});
```

Comment: Where is `"scrollChanged"` defined at `events` object? What is `fn`?

Comment: It's defined outside the plugin in the website's normal script file so it can be used for several functions.

Comment: Why do you use `if (this.events[eventName]) {` if `"scollChanged"` is not defined within `events` object? Is `events.scrollChanged` defined at `events.on( 'scrollChanged', self.translate(var1, var2) );` ?

Comment: No, it's defined in the emit function (last code snippet op my post). An as said, if I don't pass the other two params on the subscribe (events.on()) function, everything works well, but if I include them, I get the errors.

Comment: Would `this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];` define `this.events[eventName]` as a string? Then at next line `this.events[eventName].push(fn);`? Passing `self.translate(var1, var2)` would call the function immediately, instead of passing a reference to the function.

Comment: As said, I don't really understand the PubSub code, which I've found somewhere on the Internet. Ubtil now, I was glad, that it woked so well...

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr http://plnkr.co of working version?

Answer (score 0):

Pass function reference to `.on()` at second parameter instead of calling function immediately by invoking with `()`; define `rest parameters` as second parameter to `emit`, use destructuring assignment, `spread element` at `fn` to define `arguments` passed to `fn` as an array within `fn` function body

```js
var events = {
  events: {},
  on: function (eventName, fn) {
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
    this.events[eventName].push(fn);
  },
  off: function(eventName, fn) {
    if (this.events[eventName]) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.events[eventName].length; i++) {
        if (this.events[eventName][i] === fn) {
          this.events[eventName].splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      };
    }
  },
  emit: function (eventName, ...data) {
    if (this.events[eventName]) {
      this.events[eventName].forEach(function(fn) {
        fn(data);
      });
    }
  }
};

function cb() {
  var [args] = [...arguments];
  console.log(args, args[0], args[1]); // `["abc", 123]`, `"abc"`, `123`
}

events.on("scrollChanged", cb);
events.emit("scrollChanged", "abc", 123);
```

Comment: I think we're talking against each other. `events.emit("scrollChanged", yScroll);` is a global statement which has nothing to do with my plugin. This statement should only return the actual scroll value, no specific values for the plugin.

Comment: @Sam94 What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Check a working version of the reduced plugin here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgZZdk?editors=1011# I'll include the commented out code of what I want to achieve shortly.

Comment: The code is now complete. Please read the comments, I explained everything there. If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Sam94 `yScroll` is logged at `console` using your existing `javascript`; where jQuery is defined at `window` and `js` utilized is placed within `.ready()` handler `$(function() { // your js here })` https://plnkr.co/edit/bK4PiT1fQc6aFuXii71m?p=preview