# Event subscription without addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

There is an `jsfiddle` [example of the Observer pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_netkachov/ZgBrK/) in Javascript.

How Event object handles event dispatching? Where is the magic. Want to learn this but don't where to start reading. It would be great to write simple example with button and input or any other 2 plain html elements. I always used to add event listeners.

Comment: Observer pattern is a broad term. In the example you provided event listeners are added, however hidden behind a layer of abstraction. The native Event function is overwritten which is not a recommended practice.

Comment: See [PubSub script not accepting variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009949/pubsub-script-not-accepting-variables/)

Comment: `event listeners are added, however hidden behind a layer of abstraction` - I disagree - the code functions similarly to the traditional native events, but is completely unrelated to them